# Show product of two dense subsets is also dense

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, products

Problem from Conway's "A course in point set topology": If for $k=1,2, A_k$ is a dense subset of the metric space $(X_k,d_k)$, then show that $A_1\times A_2$ is a dense subset of $X_1\times X_2$.

My attempted solution: Suppose $A_k\subseteq X_k$ is dense $\Rightarrow cl(A_k)=X_k\Rightarrow \forall r_k,\space B(x_k,r_k)\cap A_k\neq \varnothing$ so take $y_k\in B(x_k,r_k)\cap A_k$. Take $r=max\{r_1,r_2\}$ so that for $(y_1,y_2)\in B((x_1,x_2),r)\Rightarrow B((x_1,x_2),r)\cap A_1\times A_2\neq \varnothing$ whenever $(y_1,y_2)\in B((x_1,x_2),r)\cap A_1\times A_2\Rightarrow (y_1,y_2)\in cl(A_1)\times cl(A_2)\Rightarrow (y_1,y_2)\in X_1\times X_2$ since both $A_1$ & $A_2$ are both dense $\Rightarrow cl(A_1\times A_2)=X_1\times X_2$

Please drop a line if you think my proof is right, and of course, let me know how to improve

Comment: Overuse of the $\Rightarrow$ symbol hurts readability.  I suggest not using it  at all.  Use words and normal English sentence structure instead.

Comment: You could use the fact that the closure of the product is the product of the closures

Comment: I know, its not my final write up. Just trying to get the ideas flowing together

Comment: I'm going off of what I learned up to this point in the book to prove this

Comment: But it's hard for someone to offer comments on your solution if they can't follow it.

Comment: Oh ok , I have not read those notes on topology, but I would recommend Munkre's book

Comment: Your use of $\Rightarrow$ is not logically correct. If you must use symbols rather than words, then the symbol you want is $\therefore$. $\phi \Rightarrow \psi$ means that if $\phi$ is true then so is $\psi$: it is neutral about the actual truth value of $\phi$.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know. I'm still pretty raw and tend to overuse the amount of math symbols.

Comment: What metric are you using on the product? The max-one ? Then you need $\min \{r_1,r_2\}$ not the max..draw a picture..

Comment: Can't remember off the top of my head, drawing a picture first probably would've helped, but I think I used it to make sure it encompassed both balls or something along that  idea

Comment: But would that really matter anyway? I tried drawing a diagram and it seems that either the minimum or maximum would both work just the same

Answer (score 3):

I’m afraid that your argument is so badly organized and confusingly written that I can’t tell whether it’s correct. From its conclusion it appears that you’re trying to prove that $\operatorname{cl}(A_1\times A_2)=X_1\times X_2$. You should begin by saying so, since there are other ways to prove that $A_1\times A_2$ is dense in $X_1\times X_2$.

To prove that $\operatorname{cl}(A_1\times A_2)=X_1\times X_2$, you could either prove the general result that $\operatorname{cl}(H\times K)=(\operatorname{cl}H)\times\operatorname{cl}K$ for arbitrary $H\subseteq X_1$ and $K\subseteq X_2$ or prove this special case. To do the latter you should start with an arbitrary point $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle\in X_1\times X_2$ and show that every open nbhd of this point intersects $A_1\times A_2$, something like this:

> Let $p=\langle x_1,x_2\rangle\in X_1\times X_2$, and let $U$ be any open nbhd of $p$. Then there are real numbers $r_1,r_2>0$ such that $p\in B(x_1,r_1)\times B(x_2,r_2)\subseteq U$. $A_1$ is dense in $X_1$, so there is a $y_1\in B(x_1,r_1)\cap A_1$; similarly, there is a $y_2\in B(x_2,r_2)\cap A_2$. Clearly $$\langle y_1,y_2\rangle\in \big(B(x_1,r_1)\times B(x_2,r_2)\big)\cap(A_1\times A_2)\subseteq U\cap(A_1\times A_2)\;.$$ Thus, every open nbhd of $p$ contains a point of $A_1\times A_2$, so $p\in\operatorname{cl}(A_1\times A_2)$. And $p$ was an arbitrary point of $X_1\times X_2$ so $\operatorname{cl}(A_1\times A_2)=X_1\times X_2$.

Note that I’ve used a lot more words than you did: I use them as connective tissue to make the flow of logic clearer. I agree completely with Nate Eldredge’s comments: except in formal logic a proof should be written in ordinary prose, with symbols only where they are necessary or genuinely make things clearer. (For instance, the quadratic formula is **much** clearer when written in algebraic symbols than when it is expressed in words!)

Comment: Hi professor Scott, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719652/the-product-of-continuous-function-is-continuous)? I think I found a good answer but I'm not sure about.

Comment: Thank you for the help on the problem, as well as for the advice, I just find it natural to condense an answer down as simple as possible without using much language to get your point across.

Comment: @Jaider: You’re welcome. The problem with that is that it makes it hard for others to read; of course this doesn’t matter in one’s notes for one’s own use, but it’s a bit of a problem when one is writing things up for others to read.